# Bootstrap vs ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-class

I use bootstrap to create a table, but if there is some value in a row I change background with ng-class`s help but the priority of bootstrap doesn't give me to do it, what shall I do? Sorry if my English is not so well)

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="objs in Objects" ng-click="param=!param" ng-class='{red : objs.state == "Rejected"}'>
```

Comment: do you mean the bootstrap rules are overriding your rules.... can you share the table classes

Comment: Use `!important` in your `red` class.

Comment: check css specifity to get a better idea! worst case scenario use !important

Comment: !important doesn't give anything, i use "table-striped" and ng-class can't change the color

Comment: .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;

Comment: this is the code from bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the rule to a more specific one using [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr.red td, .red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qf97x75r/)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there! You can simply copy the code from Bootstrap, adding your `red` selector:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd).red { 
  background-color: #FF2222;
}
```

This will ensure that your selector is **more specific** than Bootstrap's, overriding it.

Read more about CSS Specificity: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/